# Add localizations to Xcode that are used often

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization

I need to localize often the same phrases like "No ads" in different apps.
Is there any way to add words/phrases that I often localize so that Xcode localize them automatically?

Comment: Localisation can use a parameter named table. Si you can create a table for your need (ie another strings file) that contains the strings you use in multiple project (eg : stringsIUseEverywere.strings) then add the file in each project without copying it. You may have one project that is handling the versions and each project would benefit from modifications.

Comment: You can create a bundle and use it in all the apps

Comment: @PtitXav can you explain please, where can I find this parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function

```
func NSLocalizedString(
    key: String,
    tableName: String? = default,
    bundle: NSBundle = default,
    value: String = default,
    comment: String) -> String
```

In your project create a strings file with same format as default one (Localizable.strings). Then you can add the localisation for different languages.

To use it (assume the file name in your bundle is myCommonsStrings.strings :

```
let noAdd = NSLocalizedString(key: "NoAdd",
                              tableName: "myCommonsStrings",
                              comment: "No add string”)
```